# Windump via a python subprocess and PyQt Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, scapy

The simple idea is that user inputs duration in seconds, and presses a PyQt button, that calls a function that creates a python subprocess and runs windump via it. Then time sleep is used to wait for user defined duration and then process.terminate(), terminates it (code below)

```
def windump_exec(duration):
    p = s.Popen(['windump', '-i', '3', '-w', 'packets.pcap'], stdout=s.PIPE)
    time.sleep(duration)
    p.terminate()
```

Now once this is done, scapy reads .pcap file and I show stuff on the screen in short. While this is happening QWaitingSpinner is running, and to handle this I run the above logic (including scapy) using QRunnable (code below)

```
class ThreadRunnable(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, _time, filler):
        QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.time = _time
        self.filler = filler

        self.signal = RunnableSignal()

    def run(self):
        windump_exec(self.time)
        packets = parse_data()
        self.filler(packets)
        self.signal.result.emit()
```

**The Problem** is that the windump code works fine on it's own, but inside the QThread it doesn't create an output file and hence scapy has nothing to read (open), and it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Popen with QThread you can use QProcess, in my test I have used tcpdump but I suppose that changing to windump should have the same behavior:

```
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from scapy.all import rdpcap

import psutil


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class DumpProcesor(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(singleShot=True)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.handle_timeout)

        self._pid = -1

    @property
    def process(self):
        return self._process

    @property
    def timer(self):
        return self._timer

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.started.emit()
        status, self._pid = self._process.startDetached()
        if status:
            self._timer.start()
        else:
            self.finished.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_timeout(self):
        if self._pid > 0:
            p = psutil.Process(self._pid)
            p.terminate()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.finished.emit)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.log_te = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.time_sb = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=1)
        self.start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Start"))

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.log_te, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Time (seg):"), 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.time_sb, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.start_btn, 1, 2)

        self.dump_procesor = DumpProcesor(self)
        self.dump_procesor.process.setProgram("tcpdump")
        filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "packets.pcap")
        self.dump_procesor.process.setArguments(["-i", "3", "-w", filename])

        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.dump_procesor.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.log_te.clear()
        self.start_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.dump_procesor.timer.setInterval(self.time_sb.value() * 1000)
        self.dump_procesor.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.start_btn.setDisabled(False)
        filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "packets.pcap")
        packets = rdpcap(filename)

        for packet in packets:
            t = packet.show(dump=True)
            self.log_te.append(t)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So I tried your method, but when i enter handle_timeout, it gives an error and says "process does not exist". Can't seem to get why is that, any ideas?

Comment: @saeenyoda Have you changed tcpdump with windump?

Comment: Yes I did, and status returned is right when it starts the process, but when timer timeout happens it fails to get the process with that process ID